# Hover styling only seems to work on one part of li content.

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to get the color of the li's in a ul to change when they are hovered or clicked on. Here is the relevant HTML I am working with:

```
<div class="header-pages">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><i class="ion-ios-person icon-small"></i><a href="#single-attendee"><p>Single Atendee</p></a></li>
        <li><i class="ion-ios-people icon-small"></i><a href="#group-tickets"><p>Group Tickets</p></a></li>
        <li><i class="ion-arrow-move icon-small"></i><a href="#investors"><p>Investors</p></a></li>
        <li><i class="ion-location icon-small"></i><a href="#startups"><p>StartUps</p></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

When I try to use this to style these li's, I get no effect:

```
.header-pages .main-nav li:hover,
.header-pages .main-nav li:active
 {
  color: #0198E1;
}
```

When I do just the icon or just the p, it works as I want it to, but only separately:

```
.header-pages .main-nav li p:hover,
.header-pages .main-nav li p:active
 {
  color: #0198E1;
}
```

I'm trying to get my p and i to change to the same color together when either is hovered over and because they are grouped together in li's it seems straightforward to me how this should be done, but its not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because a tags set their own color which is overriding the ul

Change the css to this:

```
.header-pages .main-nav li:hover a,
.header-pages .main-nav li:hover i {
  color: #0198E1;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jq26e85c/9/) is a snippet to demonstrate

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't seem to be changing anything. Just to clarify, I have no problem getting either the icon or the p content to change color when hovered over, but I'm trying to get them to change color together when either is hovered over.

Comment: Are you thinking that the icon is the bulletpoint? the actual icon element is empty? You closed the i tag without putting anything there? As you can see when I put something in the icon it works: https://jsfiddle.net/jq26e85c/7/

Comment: I'm using an ion icon library: http://ionicons.com/, so those icons are showing up as I want them to. They're just not getting highlighted with the p content. I think the equivalent of what I'm looking for in that fiddle would be the bullet point changing color with the link text.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I just had to add an extra line for the p: .header-pages .main-nav li:hover p , but this is what I wanted. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `inherit` to make it short and simple:

```css
i,
a,
p {
  color: inherit
}

li:hover {
  color: #0198E1;
}

/* demo purpose */
ul {list-style-type:none;}
i,a {display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
i {font-size:2em;}
* {padding:0;}
```

```html
<link href="http://ionicons.com/css/ionicons.min.css?v=2.0.1" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header-pages">
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li><i class="ion-ios-person icon-small"></i>
      <a href="#single-attendee">
        <p>Single Atendee</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><i class="ion-ios-people icon-small"></i>
      <a href="#group-tickets">
        <p>Group Tickets</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><i class="ion-arrow-move icon-small"></i>
      <a href="#investors">
        <p>Investors</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><i class="ion-location icon-small"></i>
      <a href="#startups">
        <p>StartUps</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```